# How to create a number of strings based of an array imported from a filetex?

Tags: python, arrays

I'm currently very new to python programming and encountered such problem
I have a textfile with strings separated by spaces and by new lines like this:

`UR 11199 TPO 0625  APF 1371 ABS 1126 ABT 0475 ASL 0518`

Im importing with numpy np.str and is printing out like this

```
`
[['UR' '11199']
 ['TPO' '0625']
 ['APF' '1371']
 ['ABS' '1126']
 ['ABT' '0475']
 ['ASL' '0518']]`
```

My thing is that for each line I want to condense the letters with the numbers and make a single string so that the user might type anything beyond, complementing the string like this:

`UR11199 OK`

How should I do this? tried using hsplit but didnt worked out for me

##EDIT##
Maybe I wasnt clear enough, English isnt my first language.
I need to have different strings for each line, so that a user can input data for each line like

string a == UR11199 abcd

string b == TPO0625 EFGH

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply use a list comprehension along with `.join()` like so:

```
import numpy as np

test = np.array([['UR' '11199'],
                 ['TPO' '0625'],
                 ['APF' '1371'],
                 ['ABS' '1126'],
                 ['ABT' '0475'],
                 ['ASL' '0518']])

string = " ".join([l[0] for l in list(test)])
print(string)
```

Output:

```
UR11199 TPO0625 APF1371 ABS1126 ABT0475 ASL0518
```

If you want each string separate you could just use:

```
stringList = [l[0] for l in list(test)]
print(stringList)
```

Output:

```
['UR11199', 'TPO0625', 'APF1371', 'ABS1126', 'ABT0475', 'ASL0518']
```

Print each one like so:

```
stringList = [l[0] for l in list(test)]
for c in stringList: print(c)
```

Output:

```
UR11199
TPO0625
APF1371
ABS1126
ABT0475
ASL0518
```

In fact it would be even cleaner potentially to use this for printing each separtately:

```
for l in list(test): print(l[0])
```

Comment: How would I go from that to having 6 different strings? should I use separators?

Comment: I updated the answer to show how you could get them separately in a list.

Comment: I get it now, now how should I print it in a for: command?

Comment: viaturasStringList = [l[0] for l in list(viaturasArray)]
for k in viaturasStringList:
  print(viaturasStringList[k])
  print(k)
  k+=1

Comment: @nickksoares don't use that... I updated my answer to show how to print each in a loop.

Answer (score -1):

What about that:

```
mys = "UR 11199 TPO 0625  APF 1371 ABS 1126 ABT 0475 ASL 0518"
for i, word in enumerate(mys.split()):
    print(word, end="" if i % 2 == 0 else "\n")
```

output:

```
UR11199
TPO0625
APF1371
ABS1126
ABT0475
ASL0518
```